# 12/24h Time format converter

Tags: java, beginner, datetime

I am really new at this and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of writing this code, which converts time format to 12-hour from 24-hour format, and vice-versa.

For example `07:16:35PM` converts to `19:16:35`, and `13:05:25` to `1:05:25PM`.

```
public static void convertTimeTo24(String time)
{

    if(time.substring(8,10).equals("PM") && Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0,2)) < 12)
        {
            String hour12 = time.substring(0,2);
            int hour24 = (Integer.parseInt(hour12)) + 12;

            if(hour24<24)
                {
                System.out.print(hour24+time.substring(2,8));
                }

            if(Hour24>23)
                {
                System.out.print(00+time.substring(2,8));
                }
        }

    else if(time.substring(8,10).equals("AM") && Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0,2)) == 12)
        {
        System.out.print("00"+time.substring(2, time.length()));
        }

    else
        {
       System.out.print(time.substring(0,8));
        }
}


public static void convertTimeTo12(String time)
{
    int hour24 ;
    if(Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2)) > 12 ) //check if the hr is greater than 12
        {
            hour24 = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2)) - 12; //substract 12 from the hr
            if(hour24 < 10)
                {
                System.out.println("0"+hour24 + time.substring(2, time.length())+"PM"); //print hour the hour in 24hr format
                }

            else
                {
                System.out.println(+hour24 + time.substring(2, time.length())+"PM"); //print hour the hour in 24hr format
                }
        }

    if(Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2)) == 0 )
        {
        hour24 = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2)) + 12; //print hour the hour in 24hr format
        System.out.println(hour24 + time.substring(2, time.length())+"AM"); //print hour the hour in 24hr format
        }

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
           String time = in.nextLine();      //sets time to string input
           if(time.length()<10)      //check if input is in 24hours format or 12
             convertTimeTo12(time); //call the convert function above if its 12 hrs format
           else
           convertTimeTo24(time); // calls function to convert 12hr to 24hr format

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General comments:

- try to indent your code properly - it is hard to read at the moment
- follow the language conventions: variable should start in lower case (`Hour24` => `hour24`)
- similarly, opening braces are at the end of the line, not at the beginning of a new line (like in C-like languages)
- try to do only one thing in one method - at the moment your methods do the conversion and print at the same time

Regarding your question about efficiency - a more efficient way (less time to code and fewer lines of code) would be to use existing libraries.

With Java 8, you could use the java.time API:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FMT_24 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
private static final DateTimeFormatter FMT_12 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm:ssa");

public static String convertTimeTo24(String time12) {
  LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(time12, FMT_12);
  return FMT_24.format(time);
}

public static String convertTimeTo12(String time24) {
  LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(time24, FMT_24);
  return FMT_12.format(time);
}
```

And to avoid duplicating code, you could refactor the two methods into:

```
public static String convertTimeTo24(String time12) {
  return convertFormats(time12, FMT_12, FMT_24);
}

public static String convertTimeTo12(String time24) {
  return convertFormats(time24, FMT_24, FMT_12);
}

private static String convertFormats(String fromTime, DateTimeFormatter fromFormat,
                                                      DateTimeFormatter toFormat) {
  LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(fromTime, fromFormat);
  return toFormat.format(time);
}
```

Your main method needs to be changed accordingly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `K` instead of `h` in `FMT_12`?

Comment: Mmm I don't know to be honest - I never use AM/PM so not sure if noon should be 12 or 0 - but probably 12 so it would be h.